# JUnit-Test for main() without saved objects

Tags: java, swing, testing, junit, assert

I want to test the entry point of my Swing-Application, which is designed in MVP-pattern. `public static void main (String[] args)` does nothing more then launching a `MainPresenter` with its view and model.

```
public class JMasapp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MainPresenter(new MainView(), new DataModel());            
    }
}
```

I want to test if the presenter, view and model is null. (`assertNotNull(...)`). Because of the design, i don't want to save the presenter or implement setters / getters for static objects. So

```
JMasapp jm = new JMasapp();
jm.main(new String[] {"someArg","someOtherArg"});
```

wouldn't give a reference to the objects to test. Which way is the best to solve this problem?

Comment: Why do you want to test a main method that actually doesn't do much? Why don't you simply test MainPresenter, MainView und DataModel?

Comment: I want a high coverage concerning method-calls. It's important for my exam. I already did it your way, unfortunately the main-method itself is not therefore.

Comment: Sounds like a horrible course. *shudder* Coverage is a tool, not a goal and your limitation is extremely artificial. If you really wanted to test the functionality, you could create a new Launcher class and test that, but you would end up with a still untested main method, which would be totally ok.